# geth wallet password validation

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I've been mining eth for a little while now and I've got .4 eth in my address. I want to be sure that I remember my password and validate that the eth is in my wallet on my computer. The thing is I don't know where or how to validate my password using geth or how to see how much if any eth is actually stored in my wallet on my computer. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To see how much ether you have, you can use a public scanner such as https://etherscan.io/address/(your_address), or you can sync your Geth and in the console type `eth.getBalance((your_address))`.

To check if you have the correct private key, you can again try `personal.unlockAccount((your_address))`, or you can use [MEW](https://myetherwallet.com/) either online or offline to show your wallet information. If you can unlock your account and it shows the same address, you have the correct private key.

Comment: Thanks. I did know how to check the balance online but I wanted to check it on my local machine to see if the eth was actually in my wallet on my local desktop. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried eth.getBalance((myAddress)) but it returns address is not defined. I copied the address right from `geth account list` and I tried it both with and without the preceding 0x. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You need to put it as a string, such as `eth.getBalance("0xabc..")`